# Creating a function within functions.php to change the date

Tags: date-time, pods-framework

I'm using the PODS WordPress Framework which is amazing.

I created a template with one of the fields publishing the date of an event which is done through a simple 'magic tag' like this

```
{@date_of_event}
```

This publishes the date in this format: **September, 15th 2018**

What I need to do is change the format of the date being published into a numeric version which I can do by passing the value into *my own function.*

That would be done like this:

```
{@start_date,MY_FUNCTION}
```

So, to do this I need to create a function in my functions.php file like this:

```
function MY_FUNCTION ($input) {
       return "New Input" . $input;
}
```

Now, the php time date format that I need is like this:

```
Y/m/d
```

So - **my question** - how do I insert this into the function above?

Thanks for all help and direction on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the PHP's [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and WordPress's [`date_i18n()`](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/) functions:

```
function MY_FUNCTION( $input ) {
    // Removes commas so that we'll get the proper timestamp. Otherwise, the
    // strtotime() function would return FALSE.
    $input = str_replace( ',', '', $input );

    // Retrieve the UNIX timestamp of the date.
    $timestamp = @strtotime( $input );

    // Returns the date in *localized* format.
    return date_i18n( 'Y/m/d', $timestamp );
}
```

`MY_FUNCTION( 'September, 15th 2018' )`, for example, would give you `2018/09/15`.

Comment: Thanks for that - really appreciate your help. It didn't work for me thou - is it not missing this line at the end: add_filter( 'MY_FUNCTION' );

Comment: Did you add the code to your theme functions file? (i.e. `functions.php`) By using the 'magic tag' `{@start_date,MY_FUNCTION}`, the function should be called *automatically* by the PODS framework plugin. See https://pods.io/docs/build/using-magic-tags/

Comment: Yes I did add to the functions.php file. Does it matter that the comma is actually AFTER the date? So the comma actually is placed in the above example exactly like this: 15th,

Comment: I don't really understand that, but it is necessary *for the function* to remove the comma there. Otherwise, we wouldn't get the correct timestamp - e.g. `1536969600` (correct) versus `false` (incorrect..). Try add `echo $timestamp;` after the `$timestamp = ...` in the function, and see if the value is good.

Comment: **Or** try `return 'Timestamp: ' . $timestamp . '; Date in Y/m/d: ' . date_i18n( 'Y/m/d', $timestamp );` instead of what it is now. (this is for debugging purposes) And actually, what was the output of `{@start_date,MY_FUNCTION}` before you said that the function doesn't work for you?

Comment: CJ - you were right. Sorry - I was looking at the wrong template. THANK You VERY much for all your help - works great.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you @henry =) Btw, if you don't need the *localized* date format, just replace `date_i18n()` with `date()`.

Comment: What actually is 'localized' - does that mean your local TZID International Time Zone?

Comment: More to - localized in your site's language. E.g. `15 de septiembre de 2018` in Spanish for `September 15th, 2018` .. I used Google Translate, though..

Comment: For Simplified Chinese, `2018/09/15` is `2018年9月15日` as Google Translate returned just now.. So in WordPress, I'd always use `date_i18n()`, but if you'd rather go with `date()`, then it's really up to you.. or depends on your specific requirements. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the date in a different format somewhere else:
it's far easier go into pods admin -> edit -> choose your pod / field

Go into Advance Field Options fill in your Choice into "Date format for display"

Comment: I can't because I need the date published from two different formats in same template

Comment: This should work then:
    `function MY_FUNCTION($input_date) {
        return date("Y/m/d", strtotime($input_date));         
    }`